# How to Eradicate and uninstall a software completely and delete its history?

Tags: uninstall, restore, history

I installed a kind of ebook reader to read specific books which I download from a website with specific file format ! it isn't so important ! but the important part is this :

I must enter a username and password to active this software ! and i enterd a wrong username and submited ! after that software locked ,the wrong username is  constant and software doesn't allow me to change username Not at all :(

[image]

I thoght if i uninstall it, its history would be deleted and i can enter my new correct user information, I used revo uninstaller, you uninstaller and several other softwares advance uninstall mode   to  uninstall it compeletly , but after uninstalling i rebooterd pc and I installed it again , unfortunately  its username is the previous wrong and unchangeable username too :(

I dont know how can i return the software to the first day ?
i dont want to change windows  !
how it can find wrong stored ? i delete all its information wwhile  uninstalling , with revo unistaller pro ! 
please help me return the software to the first day !

windows 7 Ultimate

Comment: The simplest solution is to contact the author of the program itself and request assistance. There are so many ways the author of the program could have done something its not possible to list all of them.

Comment: Try using [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to figure out where it's reading that info from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many software will put entries into Registry, it is likely that you need to find and delete those entries in order to start fresh.

Comment: Search the registry for the wrong username you entered and either correct it or just delete it.

Answer (score 0):

When you used Revo did you choose the most advanced "uninstall mode"? If not you will need to go back and install/uninstall again this time selecting the advanced option.